# Mysql - Select from another table, operand should contain 1 column(s) error

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql tables and I would like to choose on those IDs that have a count larger than 2 from another table.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM `firsttable` where from_user_id in (SELECT target,count(*) as c FROM `second table`where type='follower' group by target having c>2)
```

But I run into the operand should contain 1 column(s) error (also, the query seems to take ages whenever I do select from xy where z in (select ...) queries).

Comment: A subquery on the right side of an `IN` operand should return only one column. You can use: `HAVING count(*) > 2` instead of putting that in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: In regards to the slowness you should try using the second table in a join instead.

Comment: Thank you, how would the join query work in this instance?

Comment: Move the subquery up into the `FROM` clause and join it to `firsttable` on `from_user_id = target`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `in` operator is only usable with single column queries. Fortunately, you don't have to have the `count` in your select list in order to have it in your `having` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   `firsttable` 
WHERE  from_user_id IN (SELECT   target
                        FROM     `second table`
                        WHERE    type =' follower' 
                        GROUP BY target 
                        HAVING   COUNT(*) > 2)
```